# Windows: how to downgrade Internet Explorer 8 to an older version?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I need to demote my IE to 7. Please tell me how to do that.

I have some links that don't support(?!!) Internet Explorer 8; they work only in IE 7 or older versions. I tried installing IE 7, but the Setup program doesn't run, saying "there is more updated version".

Comment: Goodness gracious. Why?

Comment: I am not happy doing it .. but I have got some link which doesn't support(?!!) windows Internet explorer 8 .. Link is related to business .. otherwise I would have mentioned it ..

Comment: Can you give us the link?

Comment: Certainly the accepted answer has got a point but anyway if you have decided to UNINSTALL IE8 .. then followup my answer written below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

seems nobody know about Comptability View feature in IE8, its was specialy designed to correct such issues you may have with old entreprise web-applications or such. you don't have to downgrade.

> Internet Explorer 8 is a new release
>   and some websites may not yet be ready
>   for the new browser. Click the
>   Compatibility View toolbar button to
>   display the website as viewed in
>   Internet Explorer 7, which will
>   correct display problems like
>   misaligned text, images, or text
>   boxes. This option is on a per site
>   basis and all other sites will
>   continue to display with Internet
>   Explorer 8 functionality. When you
>   click on the Compatibility View button
>   for a site, you don’t need to do it
>   again as the next time you visit that
>   site the browser will show it in
>   compatibility mode. If for some reason
>   you’d like to go back to browsing with
>   Internet Explorer 8 functionality on
>   that site, simply click the
>   Compatibility View button again.

[image]

more info at [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx)

Comment: Oh ! ok ! bt its too late to try ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [How do I uninstall or remove Internet Explorer 8?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700). It's a microsoft support article. If you installed ie 8 prior to XP sp3 you're out of luck and can't remove it. If you cannot get it to uninstall you can try installing another copy of windows into a virtual machine and use IE 7 from there.

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft Support, "[How do I uninstall or remove Internet Explorer 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700)" should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Open CMD and run this command

`%windir%\ie8\spuninst\spuninst.exe`

Now go head with uninstallation .. The important thing is **You need to install any of the previous version of IE after that uninstallation**

Answer (score 0):

You could install [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html) with [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419).

If you upgraded from IE 7 to 8, you may be able to go into add/remove programs, show updates, and then remove the update.

Comment: that "LINK" is supported only in IE 7 or its OLDER versions ..

Comment: Try firefox with IE tab https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419

Comment: doesn't work too ..

Comment: How would using Firefox with IE Tab help?? It's still running the same version of IE as the user has installed.

Comment: ya you are right ...